# SubSonic ActiveRecord templates: generated code produces error converting int? to int

Tags: c#, activerecord, subsonic3

I just started exploring SubSonic 3's ActiveRecord, and it's initial code generation has created errors.

```
    Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. 
    An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Here's the line it throws the exception on:

```
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.pkEmp;
    }
```

The exception is understandable since the column `pkEmp` is defined as `int? _pkEmp;`.  Any ideas on why the two are out of sync?

Comment: Is your primary key column nullable? I don't think SubSonic supports that.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me narrow it down.  We have some testing tables filled with dummy data for which the primary keys were never flagged as "not null".

Answer (score 3):

There can be no null value in the column defined as primary key. If so, make sure you have a problem with join (if the entity comes from a "View").

Answer (score 1):

As John Sheehan pointed out, it's important to make sure that any primary keys are not nullable (and why would they be?).